# How to force a childclass to implement and call a specific function containing body?

Tags: php, oop

I want to force a childclass of an abstract class to call a specific function. i found the solution in using an abstract function but when i try it throws an error that an abstract function cannot contain body :/ is there another way to force a class that extends my abstract class to call a predefined protected or final method? I want to clearify where the file is located that extends the abstract class.

**edit** if some file extends my class i cant trust that class so i will force the class to tell my abstract class where it is located and then search for the file based on name conventions. abstract methods cannot contain body so i have to pass it as parameter but thats not so secure in my opinion. i havent found another solution by now.

i also found the function get_class('parent') is it really safe or can someone manipulate the result?

fg

Comment: Have you considered calling the method in the constructor?

Comment: i have searched for some magic constants but havent found any. if some file extends my class i cant trust that class so i will force the class to tell my abstract class where it is located and then search for the file based on name conventions. abstract methods cannot contain body so i have to pass it as parameter but thats not so secure in my opinion. i havent found another solution by now.